# Redis in Nodejs on Cloud9 IDE: [Error: Auth error: undefined]

Tags: node.js, authentication, redis, cloud9-ide

Here is my code:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    server = require("http").createServer(app),
    io = require("socket.io").listen(server),
    redis = require("redis"),
    env = {PORT: process.env.PORT || 8080, IP: process.env.IP || "localhost"};

client = redis.createClient(env.PORT , env.IP);
client.on("error", function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

server.listen(env.PORT);
console.log("Server started @ " + env.IP + ":" + env.PORT);
```

After trying to run, I received the followings on the console:

```
Running Node Process
Your code is running at 'http://modified.address.c9.io'.
Important: use 'process.env.PORT' as the port and 'process.env.IP' as the host in your scripts!
info: socket.io started
Server started @ modified.ip.address.1:8080
[Error: Auth error: undefined]
```

I tried establishing the connection, and it connects to the IP and PORT perfectly. However, the error `[Error: Auth error: undefined]` appears and stops there. I Googled the error, the supports from the IDE I used..., and surprisingly, there are only 7 links to my problems. So I think it may be a hole in my knowledge or it is not really a problem yet a thing I don't know to work it out. All I could pull out from those Google results were (I was not sure) I need to use `client.auth(pass)` right after creating it. But where should I find the password? When I installed it `npm install redis` I didn't configure anything and wasn't told to set password whatsoever. So I reach the impasse.

I use Cloud9 IDE (c9.io), and the modules used as shown in the code above.

----With best regards,
----Tim.

Comment: check this example https://github.com/joaomajesus/rss-redis-socketio-pubsub/blob/master/server.js

Comment: The settings you are giving is making node and redisClient use same port - 8080. What is the port for redis server that you have started ?

Comment: They all listen to the same port `process.env.PORT = 8080` like the console suggests. Are they supposed to run at the same port? The link to access the website or to listen to on my workspace is not included the port, which means I have no choice but to use process.env.PORT and process.env.IP for settings, that forces them to listen to the same 8080 port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out what was wrong.

I did install Redis, but that is a Redis library that acts like a bridge between Redis driver and NodeJS. On Cloud9, I have to manually install Redis, too.

So it would take 2 commands to actually install Redis:

Install the Redis Driver on Cloud9

```
nada-nix install redis
```

Install Redis library for NodeJS

```
npm install redis
```

Thanks for anyone who was trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the redis-server using your own config file.You can create your own config like below.

```
 //port and ip of ur redis server
  port 6371
  bind 127.0.0.1
  //password for this server
  requirepass ucanmentionurpwd
  //storing snapshots of the data 
  save 60 1
  dbfilename dump.rdb
  dir /tmp/db

  //starting redis server
   redis-server //ur config file location
```

See this link for redis configuration
 https://raw.github.com/antirez/redis/2.6/redis.conf

If you mention requirepass with your password means only you need to do

```
         client.auth('urPwd');
```

Otherwise no need to call the client.auth method.

Comment: Seems like what I need. But where can I find my password? I don't know where the file is put. And when I try to start the server manually `redis-server`, it shows that `bash: redis-server: command not found`. I'm pretty sure I installed Redis.

Comment: @cuzmAZN ok.u installed redis thats fine.have u installed redis-server.no means u should install that redis-server..